# AccessViolationException when trying to put managed data into glTexImage3D

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opengl, memory-management, casting, c++-cli

I have an error when trying to read some data into an opengl Texture. My error is the following:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in libCoin3D.dll
```

It happens when I call the function glTexImage3D in the below function. If I comment out that function, then the program runs fine, but I need to construct a texture from the int array I pass into the function.

```
GLuint TextureHandler::create3DTextureBonePreview(int* d, Vector3 length){
    GLuint bindLocation;
    glGenTextures(1, &bindLocation);


    static_cast<char*>(static_cast<void*>(d));

    int w=length.x;
    int h=length.y;
    int l=length.z;
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, bindLocation);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);


    glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0,GL_RGBA,w, h, l, 0,GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,d);
    printf("Done creating texture\n");

    return bindLocation;
}
```

I think it has to do with how I am handling the memory in int* d. This data starts out as just a regular int array in some C# code and is filled in shortly afterward.

```
 int[] allDatint=new int[dataSize];
```

But from this C#, allDatint is passed to a Managed C++ constructor that takes it as an system array:

```
CallbackNode::CallbackNode(int w ,int h, int l, array<int>^ d)
```

In that constructor, it is converted to int* before it is passed to some unmanaged C++ code

```
cli::pin_ptr<int> pArrayElement = &d[0];
mCube=new MasterCube(w,h,l,pArrayElement);
```

The unmanaged C++ accepts it as an int*

```
MasterCube::MasterCube(int w,int h, int l, int* d)
```

And then passes it to the function above, converting it first to a char array to be accepted by glTexImage3D.

```
static_cast<char*>(static_cast<void*>(d));
```

What I have looked up about AccessViolationException leads me to believe that the data in 'int* d' is corrupt or not usable by glTexImage3D. Can someone tell me if there is a problem with how I am converting it among array/systemArray/int*/char* ? Or is it simply in the wrong format for opengl to understand it?

Answer (score 1):

> And then passes it to the function above, converting it first to a char array to be accepted by glTexImage3D.
>
> ```
> static_cast<char*>(static_cast<void*>(d));
> ```

Where is the `char *ptr` to which the casted pointer is assigned to? Just putting a variable into a cast statement doesn't "convert" the variable.

As for your actual problem. I'm pretty sure that the value of the expression `w * h * l * 4` exceeds the size of the actual array in bytes. Since you have only a naked pointer there, it's impossible to add a sanity check there.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, I didn't realize I would get that error from overstating the array size. Makes sense though. I found that I was using the wrong values for w,h, and l.

Comment: I am still having the 'System.AccessViolationException' even when I check that the original array of ints was created with w*h*l*4 number of ints in it. The same exact number are requested as bytes in the texture creation function. The problem even occurs if I substitute w=h=l=1, even though the array definitely has more than one int in it. Is there another cause for it that you know of? I did change the code to have a char* ptr receive the cast value, which is then used as a parameter to glTexImage3D.